# Clearing combobox dropdownlists from application

Tags: vb.net, loops, combobox

I am working on an assignment that requires a user to answer 20 questions( multiple choice ).  I am using the DropDownList property so the user cannot input anything other than A, B, C, or D.

Basically, I have 20 comboboxes and I have a button that clears them, but the code I should obviously be a loop, but I am not sure how to do that.

As of now, my code looks like this:

```
cboQuestion1.Items.Clear()
cboQuestion2.Items.Clear()
...
cboQuestion20.Items.Clear()
```

If anyone could shed some light on this, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All controls reside in the form's Controls collection, so one way would be to iterate that (assumes these CBOs are the only ones you wish to clear):

```
For Each cbo As ComboBox In Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
   cbo.Items.Clear
Next
```

Another way is to store the names of the target controls in a `List(of String)`.  Think of this as a shopping list of the controls you wish to track or treat in some special way:

```
Private myCBONamesList As List(of String)
'...
myCBONamesList.Add("cboQuestion1")
' etc
' add many/all at once:
myCBONamesList.Addrange(New String(){"cboQuestion1", "cboQuestion2" ...etc})
```

The `New String()` creates a temp array containing the literal values listed (in `{}`) and the whole thing is passed to your List to populate it.  To use it:

```
For Each s As String in myCBONamesList
    Controls(s).Items.Clear
Next
```

This method allows you to target certain CBOs and leave others alone.

Comment: I tried your first option and I am getting an error with cbo.Clear().  It is saying that Clear is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Combobox

Comment: sorry, that should have been `cbo.Items.Clear`; we want to clear the items collection as you have in your OP

Comment: Thank you!  I have a message box that pops up that asks "Are you sure you want to clear out your answers" and when I press yes it clears them out perfectly, BUT, when I press no, it also clears them out.  I am using an IF statement that says if they press yes, clear the combo boxes.  How do I say if user presses "no", do nothing?

Comment: that sounds like it is coming from your code - code we cant see.  Best to ask a new question with the relevant info.  (The `IF` is probably malformed)

Comment: [code]
Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear your answers?", "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            For Each cbo As ComboBox In Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
                cbo.Items.Clear()
            Next
        End If


    End Sub
[/code]

Comment: Best to ask a new question because code does not format in comments and this is a new problem/question...

Answer (score 0):

<s>It may or may not be the *best* way, but you could add all of your combo boxes to a `List` and then iterate over the list to clear them all.</s>

Just iterate over the [Form's Controls collection.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of iterating over the Forms Controls collection with filtering to make sure you don't accidentally clear a non-question ComboBox:

```
For Each cbo As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
    If cbo.Name Like "cboQuestion*" Then
        cbo.Items.Clear()
    End If
Next
```

**Edit:** Or if you're into one-lining things:

```
For Each cbo As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox).Where(Function(x) x.Name Like "cboQuestion*")
    cbo.Items.Clear()
Next
```